# Running Threads in specific order

Tags: java

i have question.
I just started using Threads and im pretty lame at it.
Iam working on some task.

Let's say i have 3 Threads. Every Thread's main mission is to write 1 line from .txt and so on to the end of file.
I managed to do this but i don't know how to propely use wait() and notify().
My program runs like that:

```
t1 writes line 
t2 writes line 
t1 writes line 
t2 writes line 
t3 writes line 
t2 
t1 
t2 
t3
t2 
t1 ...
```

when i synchonized my Thread using some object. In every new Thread run() method I typed also notifyAll() and wait() method. But it dosent work like it should be, which is:

```
t1
t2
t3
t1
t2
t3
...
```

Any tips guys? I would be thankfull.

tldr: How to notify t2 to be launched after t1, and t3 after t2, and t1 after t3 and so on?

Comment: The way you are trying tos ynchronize your threads kind of violates the value of threading, which is to run multiple jobs asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest solution using just Thread class:

```
thread1.start();
thread1.join();
thread2.start();
thread2.join();
thread3.start();
thread3.join();
```

But does it really help? Why create them as threads if you want to run them sequentially anyways?

Comment: This way kills my threads and i don't want to do this. They have to work in background and wait for their turn.

Comment: Or just `thread1.run(); thread2.run(); thread3.run();` ;) + 1

Answer (score 0):

> They have to work in background and wait for their turn.

In that case you can have one thread run all of them.

> How to notify t2 to be launched after t1, and t3 after t2, and t1 after t3 and so on?

```
new Thread(() -> {
    thread1.run();
    thread2.run();
    thread3.run();
}).start();
```

This runs the tasks in the background, one at a time.

Comment: They are running but in random order. How to notify exacly t2 to have access to data which other threads using too?

Comment: @iboan I would pass a Context object which has all the information each thread needs, this can be passed to every thread/task so they can see each others data.